# Oracle: Coercing VARCHAR2 and CLOB to the same type without truncation

Tags: performance, oracle, casting, clob, coerce

In an app that supports MS SQL Server, MySQL, and Oracle, there's a table with the following relevant columns (types shown here are for Oracle):

```
ShortText VARCHAR2(1700) indexed
LongText CLOB
```

The app stores values 850 characters or less in ShortText, and longer ones in LongText. I need to create a view that returns that data, whichever column it's in. This works for SQL Server and MySQL:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ShortText IS NOT NULL THEN ShortText
    ELSE LongText
  END AS TheValue
FROM MyTable
```

However, on Oracle, it generates this error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CLOB
```

...meaning that Oracle won't implicitly convert the two columns to the same type, so the query has to do it explicitly. Don't want data to get truncated, so the type used has to be able to hold as much data as a CLOB, which as I understand it (not an Oracle expert) means CLOB, only, no other choices are available.

This works on Oracle:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ShortText IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CLOB(ShortText)
    ELSE LongText
  END AS TheValue
FROM MyTable
```

However, performance is amazingly awful. A query that returns LongText directly took 70-80 ms for about 9k rows, but the above construct took between 30 and 60 *seconds*, unacceptable.

So:

1. Are there any other Oracle types I could coerce both columns to
   that can hold as much data as a CLOB? Ideally something more
   text-oriented, like MySQL's LONGTEXT, or SQL Server's NTEXT (or even
   better, NVARCHAR(MAX))?
2. Any other approaches I should be looking at?

---

Some specifics, in particular ones requested by @Guido Leenders:

```
Oracle version: Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.1.0 64bit Production
Not certain if I was the only user, but the relative times are still striking.

Stats for the small table where I saw the performance I posted earlier:
  rowcount: 9,237
  varchar column total length: 148,516
  clob column total length: 227,020
```

Comment: If you were to put all of shorttext into longtext and only have a CLOB column does that makes things quicker?

Comment: Easier yes, but as indicated above, the short one is indexed, which I'm pretty the CLOB one can't be. It can also be joined against, and supports equals tests in the WHERE clause. This is part of some generic storage infrastructure, where subsets of the data get used for specific purposes, so those features are valuable when it's known that the particular data in question always fits in the short column.

Comment: Note that Oracle 12c increases the maximum size of a varchar2 to 32,767.

Comment: @David Aldridge: Good to know, will be helpful in the future, but for now, the app needs to support older Oracle versions too.

Answer (score 1):

The to_clob is pretty expensive, so try to avoid it. But I think it should perform reasonable well for 9K rows. Following test case based upon one of the applications we develop which has the similar datamodel behaviour:

```
create table bubs_projecten_sample
( id number
, toelichting varchar2(1700)
, toelichting_l clob
)

begin
  for i in 1..10000
  loop
    insert into bubs_projecten_sample
    ( id
    , toelichting
    , toelichting_l
    )
    values
    ( i
    , case when mod(i, 2) = 0 then 'short' else null end
    , case when mod(i, 2) = 0 then rpad('long', i, '*') else null end
    )
    ;
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
```

Now make sure everything in cache and dirty blocks written out:

```
select *
from   bubs_projecten_sample
```

Test performance:

```
create table bubs_projecten_flat
as
select id
,      to_clob(toelichting) toelichting_any
from   bubs_projecten_sample
where  toelichting is not null
union all
select id
,      toelichting_l
from   bubs_projecten_sample
where  toelichting_l is not null
```

The create table take less than 1 second on a normal entry level server, including writing out the data, 17K consistent gets, 4K physical reads. Stored on disk (note the rpad) is 25K for toelichting and 16M for toelichting_l.

**Can you further elaborate on the problem?**

Please check that large CLOBs are not stored inline. Normally large CLOBs are stored in a separate system-maintained table. Storing large CLOBs inside a table can make going through the table with a Full Table Scan expensive.

Also, I can imagine populating both columns always. You still have the benefits of indexing working for the first so many characters. You just need to memorize in the table using an indicator whether the CLOB or the shortText column is leading.

As a side note; I see a difference between 850 and 1700. I would recommend making them equal, but remember to check that you are creating the table using character semantics. That can be done on statement level by using: "varchar2(850 char)". Please note that Oracle will actually create a column that fits 850 * 4 bytes (in AL32UTF8 at least, there the "32" stands for "4 bytes at most per character"). Good luck!

Comment: Hmmm, don't think inline CLOB storage or not can be the difference, given the relative timings of my  query above that returned the raw LongText value vs TO_CLOB(LongText). I wonder why your example is so much faster than what I see. The dev server I'm hitting isn't super powerful, but it's not helpless either, and performance on other things (like the raw LongText version of the query) is ok if not fantastic. Re columns lengths, thanks for your feedback. Not to wimp out, but I'll forward it to the dev who made those decisions, I'm not that strong on Oracle myself.

Comment: Not super important, but it turns out the column size mismatch was an artifact of the way I got that info, not the column itself. Thanks again for pointing it out though.

Comment: What is the exact Oracle version you are performance testing on? Are you the sole user when benchmarking?Can you include in your question the DDL to recreate the table and the exact statistics (row count, sum(length(clob)), sum(length(text)) field?) The performance difference is indeed weird.

Comment: Added the specifics you requested to the original question, in part so they could be multiline. Don't have the original DDL available from here, but the specs for the two relevant columns are as stated. And thanks for chiming in!

Comment: Hmm, given the stats you put in the question it doesn't matter whether the clobs are stored inline or outside, it is all very small, just a few bytes per record. On 11.2.0.1 I don't know about clob issues, just recall something about problems with describing the metadata to correct datatype on number columns (precision/scale lost). Access to the SGA should not be a problem and sufficient resources dito. It is really too little to be influenced by others. Can you try to rewrite as a UNION ALL and then state performance figures? It is really small data and then same scenario takes longer.

Comment: Not following you about the UNION ALL, sorry, please clarify. And while the toy data where I saw that kind of performance is very small, some customers have millions of rows in that table. They'll be accessing only segments of it at a time, relatively rarely through the views I'm thinking about, each of which is constrained to certain subsets of it, based on other columns that are indexed.

Comment: I hate to say this without an explanation, but today my results are a bit better. Still scary, but not as bad. SELECT TO_CLOB(ShortText) took about 13 sec for 9k+ rows, but in general that's not something the app will do in the real world. Restricted more realistically to return 1k+ rows, it took ~1100ms, still bad but better. One thing that's clear is that without TO_CLOB, the first run of the query is slower, but subsequent ones get internally cached or otherwise optimized, and speed up a lot. TO_CLOB blocks that, it never runs any faster. For real world use, that's unfortunate.

Comment: Tested it on SE1 11.2.0.3 server here, table with 1,3 M rows as described. Going through it with the query with union all it takes 911 msecs (from cache). Second execution 617 ms. Remember that Oracle can only run well with sufficient memory. It is CPU-bound. When memory bound it will badly perform. With 'union all' I mean: use select id
,      to_clob(ShortText)
from   MyTable
where  ShortText is not null
union all
select id
,      LongText
from   MyTable
where  LongText is not null